# Perform onload() in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to load a function when a page loads.So how to use native javascript onload function in ionic.Here is sample html page.

```
<ion-view title="Account" >
  <ion-content class="has-header padding">
    <h1>Account</h1>
    <button id="bt">test</button>
</div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

here is my javascript file

```
function testload(){

  alert("page loaded");
 }
```

I want to load the this when page is loaded.How it possible in ionicframework?

Comment: ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.log('view loaded');
   }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using the controller associated with that view?

```
.controller('YourCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Something) {
    alert("page loaded");
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Please give this a try.

```
$ionicView.enter

$ionicView.loaded
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

Answer (score 1):

do you mean on page load, or on view loaded?

pageload is simple, you could do a

```
<body onload='testload()'>
```

Comment: In case you'll need to use this, this is not permitted due to security reasons. use `(load)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

probably you should check out [$ionicPlatform](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/)
if you want to execute some function upon device ready

```
$ionicPlatform.ready([callback])
```

Or just a page load...in your controller, inject $scope and listen to $ionicView.loaded

```
app.controller('controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function(event) {
  });
});
```